# WebViewClient class does not gets instantiated in android 3.1

Tags: android, webviewclient

Facing a problem when specified url gets redirected to another one. I have implemented webviewclient for my webview. The webviewclient class gets called for android 2.3 and below, but wont for android 3.1.

Below is my code.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.abc);
             WebView ww = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
             ww.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             ww.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);

             String ggurl = "https://twitter.com/"+twitter_url;
             ww.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
             ww.loadUrl(ggurl); 
     }
         public class Callback extends WebViewClient
     {  
    @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
            {

          if(url.equals("http://www.abc.com/misc/not_found.php"))
               {
            System.out.println("Not found url thrown...");
            url="http://www.abc.com/index";
            ww.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
            ww.loadUrl(url);
               }
        else
               {
            System.out.println("Found page of college thrown");
               }

        return false;
            }

     }
  }
```

Suggest me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue; For `http://` the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` wont work.

Have to use `onPageFinished()` All the code inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` must be inside `onPageFinished().`